# Loop through url-list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am new to python and I have list of url in array and I am iterate list but i am getting error

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

while fetching url. Online [code Editor here](https://onlinegdb.com/rktQ7CZmX) what I am doing wrong.Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


lists = ["https://prod-video-eu-central-1.pscp.tv/Kxf6yJwqKtM611tEBKt0kPlPMKdDsrPZDhjluIPeiCz0XsSq-utkVn2kQk2JdaH3rdLCQc3lqjfnmHZtxa-Xzw/live_thumbnail/eu-central-1/eyJkIjowfQ/latest.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIyIn0.eyJBbGxvd2VkUHJvdG9jb2xzIjpbInRodW1iIl0sIkJyb2FkY2FzdElkIjoiMW1ueGVvRHJlVm9HWCIsIkdyYW50VHlwZSI6InJlYWQiLCJHcmFudGVkQXQiOjE1MzExNDM3MzksIkdyYW50ZWRUbyI6IndlYi1yYXRlLWxpbWl0ZWQtNWM5MmJjNmNhZGJiNjdmZjcxZGViMmQzNGQ2NWNjMmYiLCJTdHJlYW1OYW1lIjoiS3hmNnlKd3FLdE02MTF0RUJLdDBrUGxQTUtkRHNyUFpEaGpsdUlQZWlDejBYc1NxLXV0a1ZuMmtRazJKZGFIM3JkTENRYzNscWpmbm1IWnR4YS1YenciLCJleHAiOjE1MzEzMTY1Mzl9.4zU4iPPcrG1pXAl3zNu4Yn1GatUl2kJtja33Zbkpkjk&service=proxsee&digest=7I3s5DHm3nr5QEyw2OM5wvmoP3bUdmrE9ffn5WHZ_a0&ts=765571869",
         "https://prod-video-eu-central-1.pscp.tv/Kxf6yJwqKtM611tEBKt0kPlPMKdDsrPZDhjluIPeiCz0XsSq-utkVn2kQk2JdaH3rdLCQc3lqjfnmHZtxa-Xzw/live_thumbnail/eu-central-1/eyJkIjowfQ/latest.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIyIn0.eyJBbGxvd2VkUHJvdG9jb2xzIjpbInRodW1iIl0sIkJyb2FkY2FzdElkIjoiMW1ueGVvRHJlVm9HWCIsIkdyYW50VHlwZSI6InJlYWQiLCJHcmFudGVkQXQiOjE1MzExNDM3MzksIkdyYW50ZWRUbyI6IndlYi1yYXRlLWxpbWl0ZWQtNWM5MmJjNmNhZGJiNjdmZjcxZGViMmQzNGQ2NWNjMmYiLCJTdHJlYW1OYW1lIjoiS3hmNnlKd3FLdE02MTF0RUJLdDBrUGxQTUtkRHNyUFpEaGpsdUlQZWlDejBYc1NxLXV0a1ZuMmtRazJKZGFIM3JkTENRYzNscWpmbm1IWnR4YS1YenciLCJleHAiOjE1MzEzMTY1Mzl9.4zU4iPPcrG1pXAl3zNu4Yn1GatUl2kJtja33Zbkpkjk&service=proxsee&digest=7I3s5DHm3nr5QEyw2OM5wvmoP3bUdmrE9ffn5WHZ_a0&ts=765571869"]
for index,value in enumerate(lists):
    urllib.request.urlopen(value)
```

Comment: You are doing nothing "wrong". The URL you try to open simply does not exist.

Comment: Why do you need `enumerate` here?

Comment: @ sven url is working

Comment: Your third url doesn't work. There is no image there. First two urls are working.

Comment: i remove 3rd url but problem is same I am geeting error as all two are working URL

Comment: Are you sure you've properly removed it? I don't get any error with that code.

Comment: problem was url not working but after updating url code work fine.Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Checking](https://monitorbacklinks.com/seo-tools/http-header-status-check) the **HTTP status code** of the URLs you've provided, I get:

`Response: 404 Not Found` for your URL `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y4vD9LM2z3k/hqdefault_live.jpg`.

Thus, your third link just doesn't work and when requesting to open it with `urllib`, it returns `404` error.
The other two links work, you don't have a problem with them and your program should not return any error when only using them.

P.S.: Why use `enumerate`, when you can just:

```
for link in lists: 
    urllib.request.urlopen(link)
```

Comment: problem was url not working but after updating url code work fine.Thanks